# When and how to use C++ htonl function

Tags: c++, htonl

```
cout << "Hello World !" << endl;
```

For my very first post on stack**overflow**: When are we supposed to use the `htonl` function? I have gone through the man page. However, I don't really understand when and how to use it.

Comment: Whenever you are sending a 4 byte value to a different machine. The receiving machine then uses `ntohl` to recover the value.

Comment: You need it only if you are doing network programming or sharing binary data between different computer architectures.  There's the corollary function `ntohl`, which is actually the [same function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617684/when-is-htonlx-ntohlx-or-when-is-converting-to-and-from-network-byte-o) as htonl on the same platform..  There's also `htons` and `ntohs` for 2-byte values.

Comment: It is worth mentioning, many modern applications transmit data textually, such as with XML over HTTP. But, lower level programming will deliver data in binary, and the world of computing is still heterogeneous.

Comment: Thank you for all the useful information !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**H**ost **TO** **N**etwork translation. It makes sure the [endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of a 32 bit data value is correct (Big endian) for network transport. `ntohl` -- **N**etwork **TO** **H**ost -- is used by the receiver to ensure that the endian is correct for the receiver's CPU.
Keep an eye out for `htons` and `ntohs` for handling 16 bits, and out there somewhere are likely `htonll` and `ntohll` for 64 bits.

Using all of them is as simple as pass in the number you want converted and out comes the converted number. You may find that absolutely nothing has happened on some processors because their endian is already big.

```
uint32_t inval = 0xAABBCCDD;
uint32_t outval = htonl(inval);
```

Will, on most desktop hardware, result in outval being set to `0xDDCCBBAA`