# How to determine endianness at compile-time?

Tags: c++

How can I determine at compile time if my platform is little endian or big endian? I have seen many ways to determine at runtime using casting, and some platform-dependent options. Is there a portable or standard way to do this?

```
constexpr bool is_little_endian = ?;
```

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239993/determining-endianness-at-compile-time, but that question is for C not C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting endianness programmatically in a C++ program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001307/detecting-endianness-programmatically-in-a-c-program)

Comment: Note that the solution presented here is the same as one in my proposed dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141476/1896169

Comment: my guess is that you want to know the endianness _so that_ ...? Most things that depend on byte order really want to translate from one to the other. This is exactly what the [htonl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386769/when-and-how-to-use-c-htonl-function) and related functions are for. I'm not discounting the question for other valid cases, but don't reinvent the wheel if you don't need to!

Comment: @Justin there is [an answer there that uses std::endian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38141476/1013719), but the question doesn't specifically ask for a compile-time solution, it seems lost in the noise. The question itself isn't a duplicate, does it become a duplicate when someone provides that answer?

Comment: @RyanHaining I'm never actually sure TBH. In this case, I believe this is a good duplicate, because many of the answers over there give compile-time solutions, as the desire for compile-time endianness detection is such a natural extension of the question

Comment: @Justin are there other portable compile-time solutions? The only other I see uses a union illegally. I'd be very interested if another one exists.

Comment: @RyanHaining Best alternative I know of is Boost: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32513998/1896169 . I can't remember the exact Boost header or the macro it defines

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++20 added [`std::endian`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/endian) to `<bit>`* which can be used in a constexpr context.

[Live example of below code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F8PtnBrBVOVWTWi7):

```
if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little) {
    std::cout << "litle endian\n";
} else if constexpr(std::endian::native == std::endian::big) {
    std::cout << "big endian\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "something silly\n";
}
```

* It was originally `<type_traits>` and will be there in older implementations.

Comment: `!= little` does not strictly imply big-endian. There are some less common strange byte orders out there.